# High-dimensional pointless varieties over finite fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field. Do there exist smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{F}_q$ of arbitrarily high dimension that have no $\mathbb{F}_q$-points and no non-constant maps to lower-dimensional varieties?

Two lines of attack that don't work: Brauer-Severi varieties (the Brauer group of $\mathbb{F}_q$ is trivial) and varieties that become simple abelian over $\mathbb{F}_q$ (they have a rational point to begin with as mentioned by Wojowu).

Comment: What do you mean by "smooth" if there are no points? Maybe geometrically smooth (namely, smooth over $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q$)?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Why is lack of points a problem for smoothness?

Comment: RE the suggestion in the edit - no, this is not possible. It is a theorem due to Lang that if a variety over a finite field which becomes an abelian variety after a base change, then it has a rational point.

Comment: What about the variety $x_1^{q-1}+x_2^{q-1}+....x_n^{q-1}=n+1$?

Comment: @LeechLattice It must be projective. You probably mean $=(n+1)x_0^{q-1}$? And even then, for $n>p$ there will be solutions already in $\mathbb F_p$: take e. g. $x_i=0$ for $i>n+1\mod p$.

Comment: @Wojowu: I was just trying to say that "smooth=smooth at each point". If you do not have points at all, then you should specify the field extension where you are looking for points.  But maybe this is implicit in this context, I am not at all an expert on varieties over finite fields.

Comment: Or maybe one considers points over $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ for all $n$?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi I believe you can just require regularity of all algebras in some  cover by affines, no?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: As $\mathbb{F}_q$ is perfect, smooth over $\mathbb{F}_q$ just means that the scheme is regular, which is defined in terms of the local rings at all scheme-theoretic points (in fact it just suffices to check the closed points, which can be thought of as Galois orbits of $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q$ points.). Also by fpqc descent, smooth over $\bar{\mathbb{F}}_q$ implies smooth over $\mathbb{F}_q$ (and naturally the latter implies the former by base change).

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explainations.

Answer (score 23):

Sure.

By Poonen's Bertini theorem, for every $q$ and $n$, the limit as $d$ goes to $\infty$ of the proportion of degree $d$ hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^n$ that are smooth and have no $\mathbb F_q$-points is positive.

Being smooth hypersurfaces in $\mathbb P^n$ for (let's say) $n>3$, they have Picard rank $1$, and thus no maps to lower-dimensional varieties.

---

For an explicit smooth hypersurface of dimension $n-2$, take $\alpha \in \mathbb F_{q^n}$ with $\operatorname{tr}(\alpha)\neq 0$. Choose a basis for $\mathbb F_{q^n}$, so that elements of $\mathbb F_{q^n}$ can be written as vectors over $\mathbb F_q$, with multiplication given by an $n$-tuple of quadratic polynomials.

Consider the function $$ \operatorname{tr} ( \alpha x^{  \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}})$$ from $\mathbb F_{q^n}$ to $\mathbb F_q$. In coordinates, this is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$ in $n$ variables, hence defines a projective hypersurface, and sends every nonzero element of $\mathbb F_{q^n}$ to a nonzero element of $\mathbb F_q$, hence has no $\mathbb F_q$-points.

Over $\overline{\mathbb F_q}$, we can choose our coordinate system to be the $n$ embeddings of $\mathbb F_{q^n}$ into $\overline{\mathbb F_q}$, and in this coordinate system the equation is $\sum_i c_i x_i^{  \frac{q^n-1}{q-1}}$ where $c_i \neq 0$ is the image of $\alpha_i$ under the $n$th embedding, so this hypersurface is also smooth.

Comment: Is there some simple explicit family of hypersurfaces that comes to mind?

Comment: @vope After thinking a bit I found one (inspired by Leech Lattice's example).

Answer (score 10):

Just take the Weil restriction with respect to $\mathbb{F}_{q^r} / \mathbb{F}_q$ of a pointless curve.  This will typically admit no $\mathbb{F}_q$-morphism to a variety of lower dimension.

Answer (score 8):

Not an answer, this is just a (cw) out-of-curiosity example of the recipe from Will Sawin's answer. The following polynomial defines a smooth projective surface without any $\mathbb F_3$-points:
$$\scriptstyle
-t^{40}-zt^{39}-x^3t^{37}-x^4t^{36}+y^4t^{36}-xy^3t^{36}-yz^3t^{36}-x^3yt^{36}-x^9t^{31}+y^9t^{31}-z^9t^{31}+x^{10}t^{30}-y^{10}t^{30}-xz^9t^{30}-yz^9t^{30}-x^9yt^{30}-y^{12}t^{28}-z^{12}t^{28}-x^3y^9t^{28}+x^3z^9t^{28}+x^9y^3t^{28}+x^9z^3t^{28}+x^{13}t^{27}-z^{13}t^{27}-xy^{12}t^{27}+yz^{12}t^{27}-x^3y^{10}t^{27}+x^4y^9t^{27}+y^4z^9t^{27}+xy^3z^9t^{27}-x^3yz^9t^{27}+x^9y^4t^{27}-x^9z^4t^{27}+y^9z^4t^{27}+x^{10}z^3t^{27}+y^{10}z^3t^{27}-xy^9z^3t^{27}+x^9yz^3t^{27}+x^{12}yt^{27}-x^{12}zt^{27}-y^{12}zt^{27}-x^9y^3zt^{27}-x^{27}t^{13}-y^{27}t^{13}-z^{27}t^{13}-xy^{27}t^{12}+xz^{27}t^{12}-yz^{27}t^{12}+y^{30}t^{10}+z^{30}t^{10}-x^3y^{27}t^{10}+y^3z^{27}t^{10}-y^{27}z^3t^{10}-x^{31}t^9-y^{31}t^9-z^{31}t^9-xy^{30}t^9+xz^{30}t^9+yz^{30}t^9+x^3y^{28}t^9-x^3z^{28}t^9-y^3z^{28}t^9+x^4z^{27}t^9+y^4z^{27}t^9+x^3yz^{27}t^9-x^{27}y^4t^9-x^{27}z^4t^9-y^{27}z^4t^9+xy^{27}z^3t^9-x^{30}yt^9-x^{30}zt^9+x^3y^{27}zt^9+x^{27}y^3zt^9-y^{36}t^4-x^9y^{27}t^4-x^9z^{27}t^4+y^9z^{27}t^4-y^{27}z^9t^4-x^{37}t^3+y^{37}t^3-z^{37}t^3-xy^{36}t^3+xz^{36}t^3+yz^{36}t^3-x^{10}z^{27}t^3-xy^9z^{27}t^3-x^{27}z^{10}t^3+y^{27}z^{10}t^3+x^{28}y^9t^3-x^{28}z^9t^3+y^{28}z^9t^3-x^{27}yz^9t^3+x^{36}yt^3-x^{36}zt^3-y^{36}zt^3-x^{27}y^9zt^3-x^{39}t-y^{39}t+z^{39}t-x^3y^{36}t+x^3z^{36}t-x^9z^{30}t-y^9z^{30}t-x^{12}z^{27}t+y^{12}z^{27}t-x^3y^9z^{27}t+x^9y^3z^{27}t-x^{27}y^{12}t-x^{27}z^{12}t+y^{30}z^9t-x^3y^{27}z^9t-x^{36}y^3t-x^{36}z^3t-y^{36}z^3t+x^{27}y^9z^3t+x^{40}-y^{40}+z^{40}-xy^{39}+yz^{39}-x^4z^{36}+xy^3z^{36}-x^9y^{31}-x^9z^{31}+y^9z^{31}+x^{10}z^{30}+xy^9z^{30}-x^{12}y^{28}+x^{12}z^{28}+y^{12}z^{28}-x^{13}y^{27}+y^{13}z^{27}-xy^{12}z^{27}-x^4y^9z^{27}-x^9y^4z^{27}-x^{10}y^3z^{27}+x^{12}yz^{27}-x^{27}y^{13}+x^{27}z^{13}+y^{27}z^{13}+xy^{27}z^{12}+x^{30}y^{10}-x^{30}z^{10}-y^{30}z^{10}-x^3y^{27}z^{10}+x^{27}y^3z^{10}-x^{31}y^9+x^{31}z^9+y^{31}z^9-xy^{30}z^9+x^3y^{28}z^9-x^4y^{27}z^9+x^{27}y^4z^9+x^{36}z^4-x^9y^{27}z^4+x^{27}y^9z^4-x^{37}y^3-x^{37}z^3+y^{37}z^3-xy^{36}z^3-x^{27}y^{10}z^3-x^{28}y^9z^3+x^{36}yz^3+x^{39}y+x^{39}z-y^{39}z+x^9y^{30}z-x^{12}y^{27}z-x^{30}y^9z+x^{36}y^3z
$$
(this is the trace of $(x+y\alpha+z\alpha^2+t\alpha^3)^{40}\alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the generator of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb F_{81}$ and $x,y,z,t\in\mathbb F_3$).

In fact, using that $x=x^3=x^5=...$ and $x^2=x^4=x^6=...$ for any $x\in\mathbb F_3$, one can turn the above into a much shorter example:
$$
-t^4-t^3 x+t^3 y+t^2 x z-t^2 y^2-t x^3-t x^2 y+t x^2 z+t x y^2+t y^3-t y z^2+t z^3+x^4+x^3 y-x^3 z+x^2 z^2+x y^2 z-x z^3-y^4-y^3 z+z^4
$$
However the latter might be non-smooth, as Will Sawin points out in the comment.

Comment: The shorter example may not be smooth, though. I suspect it's equal to the norm form, which has singularities larger fields (but you still have some freedom in how to write it, for example in the $x^3z$ and $xz^3$ terms, and it's possible the way you did is smooth).

Comment: @WillSawin Have not thought about it! Will add the warning.